# CSS single column media query

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

Trying to create a CSS media query that converts my website to single column when viewed in a web browser. (currently 3 columns)
What I have so far, I don"t think it is correct though

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
  body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .col-1 {
 background: #D7E8D4;
 flex: 1;
 background-image: url('white.jpg');
 text-align:center;
}
  .col-2 {
 padding: 4px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex: 5;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Arial Black";
 font-size: 20pt;
 background-color: #FFFF82;
}
  
}
  .col-3 {
 border-style: solid;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex: 5;
 text-align: center;
}

  .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .content > main {
    flex: 3;
    min-height: 60vh;
    text-align:center;
    border-style: solid;
  }
  .content > side {
    background: gray;
    flex: 1;
    text-align:center;
    border-style: solid;
  }
  header, footer {
    background: #FFDB4A;
    height: 30vh;
    text-align:center
   
    
  }
    
  aside, article {
 border-style:solid
}
  
  header {
 padding: 1em;
 background-image: url('acnl.jpg');
}
  .Footer {
 font-family: "Arial";
 font-size: 14pt;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 bottom: -100px;
 left: 0;
 padding: 1rem;
 background-color: #efefef;
 text-align: center;
 height: 100px;
}

p {
    white-space: normal;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    
}

li a {
 display: block;
 color: #731F02;
 padding: 8px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #53FF53;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family: "Arial Black";
}


li a:hover {
    background-color: #FF99CC;
    color: #002200;
}
li {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}

li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
@media only screen 
    and (max-device-width : 667px) 
    and (orientation : portrait) 
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1)

    {
  
 header {
  display:none;
  }
 
 .col-2{ 
  text-align:left;
  }
 .col-3 {
  width: 100%;
 }
 footer {
  display:none;
   }
 body {
  float:left;
  
   
 }
 .col-1 {
   text-align:left;
   display:list-item
 }
```

Picture Of my website currently before mobile
[web version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXqBe.png)

Code for one of the pages on site

```html
<!doctype html>
<title>Program 7</title>
<link href="cartyCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<body>

  <nav class="col-1"><ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="QRcodes.html">QR codes</a></li>
   </ul><br>
   <img alt="gift" height="238" longdesc="floating present" src="Present.gif" width="250"></nav>
  <div class="col-2">
   <header class="col-3">
  <img alt="acnl" height="160" longdesc="acnl logo" src="Animal_Crossing_Logo.png" width="240">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <img alt="leaf" height="160" longdesc="acnl leaf" src="leaf.png" width="160"></header>
    <main class="content">
    <article class="col-2">This is one of the many villagers you can get<br>
  <img alt="Fauna" height="265" longdesc="villiager" src="Fauna.png" width="200"></article>
    <aside class="col-3"><p>Animal Crossing&nbsp;is a community simulation&nbsp;video game 
  series developed and published by&nbsp;Nintendo, in which the human player 
  lives in a&nbsp;villiage&nbsp;inhabited by anthropomorphic animals, carrying out 
  various activities including fishing, bug catching, fossil hunting, etc. 
  The series is notable for its&nbsp;open ended&nbsp;gameplay and extensive use of 
  the game systems internal&nbsp;clock&nbsp;and calender&nbsp;to simulate real passage of 
  time.</p> <br>First Release:&nbsp;Animal Crossing; April 14, 2001 <br></aside>
    </main>
   <footer class="Footer">Victoria Carty<br>
   
    <a href="mailto:victoria.carty@nc.navarrocollege.edu">
  victoria.carty@nc.navarrocollege.edu</a><br>
  Beginning Web Programming | ITSE-1311-NT1-17/FA
  </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

I would also like to hide the footer and the ballon gif. under the nav buttons
Not sure what other info to add to this post to get proper help

Comment: can you provide a link to your website because its a bit difficult to understand what you are actually looking for with the help of attached picture and your CSS is also not complete.

Comment: Added full CSS sheet above, it's just a file not up on a server

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you meant by display the gif and footer under the nav buttons but the following code will clean up your column issue for mobile.

Change your media query to:

```
@media only screen 
    and (max-width : 667px) 
    and (orientation : portrait) 
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1) {
```

and inside the media query do:

```
body {
  display: block;
}
.content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I was wanting certain things not to appear in  mobile view